# how to typecase java.util.ArrayList into com.mongodb.basicdbobject

Tags: java, mongodb, junit, casting

```
 public void process(FeedExchange exchange) {
    List<BasicDBObject> defaultNavigation = (List<BasicDBObject>) exchange.getInput();
    Set<String> navigationIdList = exchange.getProperty("navigationIdList", HashSet.class);
    if (navigationIdList == null) {
      navigationIdList = new HashSet<>();
    }
    for (BasicDBObject basicDBObject : defaultNavigation) {
      String key = ((BasicDBObject)basicDBObject.get("_id")).getString("identifier");
      navigationIdList.add(key);
    }
    exchange.setProperty(FeedExchangeConstants.DEFAULT_NAVIGATION_LIST, defaultNavigation);

    if (!navigationIdList.isEmpty()) {
      exchange.setProperty("navigationIdList", navigationIdList);
      exchange.setProperty("navigationIdString", "\"" + StringUtils.join(navigationIdList, "\",\"") + "\"");
    }
  }
```

For writing junit test case for the above code i need to pass input to the default navigation
my testcase

```
public class GetDefaultNavigationTest {

  @Test
  public void testDefaultNavigation() throws Exception {
    String resourceName = "GetDefaultNavigationResponse.json";
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(resourceName).getFile());
    String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(absolutePath);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(reader, Map.class);
    System.out.println(map);

    BasicDBObject defaultNavigation = new BasicDBObject(map);
    System.out.println(defaultNavigation.toJson());
    FeedExchange exchange = new FeedExchange();
    exchange.setInput(Collections.singletonList(defaultNavigation));
    exchange.setProperty("defaultNavigationList", defaultNavigation);
    exchange.setProperty("defaultNavigation", Collections.singletonList(defaultNavigation));
}
```

My Json file is GetDefaultNavigationResponse.json
{ "_id" : [{ "collection_id" : "1234", "project_id" : "5527", "version_id" : "default", "identifier" : "53573" }] }

i have the follwing error java.util.arraylist cannot cast into com.mongodb.basicdbobject.how can i convert into array list into basicdbobject.i m beginner to java and mongodb .any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please show the exact error message and indicate which line of your code the error occurs at.

Comment: error message:java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBObject. and error occur at line  String key = ((BasicDBObject)basicDBObject.get("_id")).getString("identifier"); in process function